# SASS - generate 2 different styleguide.css

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using SASS framework and I need to override some of Foundation values (in my case it is `.row` `max-width` in generated `.css` file) for the part of pages and leave this setting unchanged for another part. 
 e.g. I have the following settings in my `styleguide.scss` file:

```
// Fixing Foundation .row-s
  .row {
    margin-left: -1 * $half-spacing-unit;
    margin-right: -1 * $half-spacing-unit;
    width: auto;
  }
```

I changed it to

```
.row {
   width: auto;
   max-width: 100% !important;
   }
```

and it's quite logical that this change will affect all generated `.css` files. How can I customize the generation of a separate `styleguide.css` for the part of the pages?

Comment: Are you using a task manager like grunt or gulp?

Comment: @Adam yes, I'm using `gulp`

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on projects where the whole site needs a different style sheet for different countries.

Say we have two countries, i would have two variable files and in here would be everything that would be different. Then i'd use grunt/gulp tasks to compile them.